# Is there an automagic tool to refactor / remove some conditionals from a large C code base?

Tags: c, refactoring, preprocessor

We have a large, C code base that we have inherited, and while we were in the process of updating all modules in it to a new framework, we created a lot of #ifdef FOO and #ifndef FOO so that we could run the new framework parallel to the old framework for testing purposes.

Now that we are out of testing phase and have done our first release, we would like to officially remove all of the legacy code (when FOO is defined).

I know about the output of the C preprocessor and that is not useful in this case, because I do not want ALL macros expanded and all header files included, so please don't respond suggesting we use that.

What we would like is a tool that can take a directory and all subdirectories, and process all text files within them to remove all of the #if #else cases where FOO is defined and likewise keep the ones where FOO is undefined, removing the entire #if/#else statement.

I would think that this is a pretty common refactoring task, and it's a lot of manual labour (easy for a tool, though!), so if anybody knows of something, please let me know!

Comment: If the defined or not defined status of `FOO` changes in different files, then the problem does not sound "easy". Where do the changes come from? Are there `#define FOO` preprocessor directives in some files?

Comment: FOO never changes, it is controlled by the makefile.  And it will never ever come back into being defined in our project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried linuxes "unifdef" commandline tool? you have to tweak a bit with shell to get it recursively working

Answer (score 0):

Clang format is about as close as you're gonna get. it'll clean up the spacing and layout of the code so you're not starting at a giant blob of text, but that's about all it can do for you because Variable names, constants, etc all derive their meaning from humans; and no program can read your mind.